# How can I scan a QR code to connect to a Wi-Fi network on Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

On various devices, both smartphones and computers, it is possible to generate a QR code for a Wi-Fi network. You can connect to that Wi-Fi network by scanning the QR code.

Ubuntu 23.04 has this functionality. You can open the Settings app, and navigate to the "Wi-Fi" section, then click the QR code button next to a Wi-Fi network.

[image: Screenshot]
([image from OMGLinux](https://www.omglinux.com/gnome-44-features/))

How can I connect to a Wi-Fi network on my Ubuntu computer by scanning a QR code? I can't find the "scan QR code" button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [wifi-qr](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man1/wifi-qr.1.html) command

```
wifi-qr option
    
           g    GUI Main Menu
    
           c    WiFi QR Create GUI
    
           t    WiFi QR Create Terminal
    
           s    QR Scan and Auto Connect WiFi
    
           q    QR Scan and Connect WiFi GUI
    
           v    WiFi-QR Version is 0.1.1
```

There is a [project in github](https://github.com/kokoye2007/wifi-qr/blob/master/README.md#wifi-share-and-connect-with-qr), that contain a script to easily accomplish this task. The project is called wifi-qr by kokoye2007. It can be cloned here.

To use the script, we need to clone the project from github.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/kokoye2007/wifi-qr
```

Once cloned, go into the project directory.

```
$ cd wifi-qr
```

To scan a QR code, and connect to the wifi information contained in the code

```
$ ./wifi-qr s
```

A camera interface will be displayed. Show our wifi QR code to the computer's webcam, and the script will read the QR code and automatically connect to the wifi using the information in the QR code.
[Connect to a wifi by scanning a QR code in Linux](https://www.linuxwave.info/2021/10/connect-to-wifi-by-scanning-qr-code-in.html?m=1)
[WiFi Share and Connect with QR](https://github.com/kokoye2007/wifi-qr/blob/master/README.md#wifi-share-and-connect-with-qr)

Comment: I can install `wifi-qr` by running `sudo apt install wifi-qr` . Is there a reason to download it from GitHub instead?

Comment: @Flimm just i trying to add more ways and sources

Comment: I suggest changing the answer to use apt install. I tried cloning the repo and got this error: "./wifi-qr: line 205: zbarcam: command not found". apt install installs this and other dependencies: The following additional packages will be installed:
  qrencode zbar-tools
Suggested packages:
  zbarcam-gtk zbarcam-qt
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  qrencode wifi-qr zbar-tools

Comment: This answer should include the apt install command, and also mention that the gui does everything you want.